# Create 1 "outer" array from multiple loops that return an "inner" array

Tags: php

The requirement is to produce a list of dates for specific days within a defined period, i.e every Thursday for May 2019 through September 2019.

Expecting the format to be:

```
Array 
    ( 
        [0] => 2019-05-02 
        [1] => 2019-05-09 
        [2] => 2019-05-16 
        [3] => 2019-05-23 
        [4] => 2019-05-30 
        [5] => 2019-06-06 
        [6] => 2019-06-13 
        [7] => 2019-06-20 
        [8] => 2019-06-27
        [9] => 2019-07-04 
        [10] => 2019-07-11 
        [11] => 2019-07-18 
        [12] => 2019-07-25  
        [13] => 2019-08-01 
        [14] => 2019-08-08 
        [15] => 2019-08-15 
        [16] => 2019-08-22 
        [17] => 2019-08-29 
        [18] => 2019-09-05 
        [19] => 2019-09-12 
        [20] => 2019-09-19 
        [21] => 2019-09-26 
    )
```

Current code is:

```
function getCompDates($y, $m) {

    $allDates = [];
    $current = strtotime("first thursday of $y-$m");
    $end = strtotime("last day of $y-$m");

    while ($current <= $end) {
        $allDates[] = date('Y-m-d', $current);
        $current = strtotime('next thursday', $current);
    }

    return $allDates;
}

$thursdays = [];
$thursdays_tmp = [];

for ($i = 5; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $thursdays_tmp[] = getCompDates(2019, sprintf('%02d', $i));
    print_r($thursdays_tmp);
}
```

I really just want the `$thursday` array to be my result. I have added the `$thursday_tmp` variable for "inner" loop processing, which then finally combines back into `$thursday`

However, by the final run of the loop, the `$thursday_tmp` array looks like:

```
Array 
    ( 
        [0] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] => 2019-05-02 
                [1] => 2019-05-09 
                [2] => 2019-05-16 
                [3] => 2019-05-23 
                [4] => 2019-05-30 
            ) 
        [1] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] => 2019-06-06 
                [1] => 2019-06-13 
                [2] => 2019-06-20 
                [3] => 2019-06-27 
            ) 
        [2] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] => 2019-07-04 
                [1] => 2019-07-11 
                [2] => 2019-07-18 
                [3] => 2019-07-25 
            ) 
        [3] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] => 2019-08-01 
                [1] => 2019-08-08 
                [2] => 2019-08-15 
                [3] => 2019-08-22 
                [4] => 2019-08-29 
            ) 
        [4] => Array 
            ( 
                [0] => 2019-09-05 
                [1] => 2019-09-12 
                [2] => 2019-09-19 
                [3] => 2019-09-26 
            ) 
    )
```

Comment: So you basically want the array to be one array, instead of one array with many sub-arrays? You got the results you desire within those arrays?

Comment: Use `array_merge` while looping for `$thursdays_tmp`

Comment: Why not just change `getCompDates` so it takes a starting and ending date, instead of just doing one month at a time?

Comment: @Qirel, yes the dates are correct. I started with manually calling the `getCompDates` function and verifying. And yes, 1 array of date items. @Barmar, the format of the function came from previous comments and learning about searching/detecting dates. What you propose to change the function parameters is another option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, just change this code at the for loop to merge all the arrays into just one:

```
for ($i = 5; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $thursdays_tmp = array_merge($thursdays_tmp, getCompDates(2019, sprintf('%02d', $i)));
}
print_r($thursdays_tmp);
```

The complete code can be seen and run here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11439d56c14229acf23ad57a07f71aa88f944040

Comment: great thanks, tried and tested = works as expected.